# Can anyone notice where the mistakes is in my code?

Tags: c

Can anyone tell me why is my output wrong "1* 3 = 1" whereas other multiplications is correct? Thanks!

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int n,i = 1, total;
    
    printf("\nPlease enter multiplication table: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    printf("%d Times Table\n",n);

    while(i<= 12)
    {   
    printf("\n%d*%d=%d", i, n, total);
    i++;
    total = i*n;
    }       
}
```

Comment: You should calculate the total *before* printing it

Comment: Wrong order of `i++` and `total = i*n;` Why do you use `while`? `for` loop will be more convenient in the context: `for (int i = 1; i <= 12; i++) {total = i*n; printf("\n%d*%d=%d", i, n, total);}`

Comment: @DmitryBychenko This is a task given by my lecturer and I had to use `while` and I was stuck at this part but I understands now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are printing a value, `total`, before you assign any value to it. On the first iteration of the `while` loop, `total` doesn't contain any defined value.

Here's a way to fix it:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int n, i = 1, total;
    printf("\nPlease enter multiplication table: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    printf("%d Times Table\n", n);
    while (i <= 12)
    {
        total= i * n;
        printf("\n%d*%d=%d", i, n, total);
        i++;
    }
}
```

Simply calculate `total` before you print it, not after.

Comment: Thanks for this precise explanation! good day to you!